# How to access a Ruby Module method

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby module for constants. It has a list of variables and one method which applies formatting.

I can't seem to access the method in this module. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 70):

If you `include` the module the method becomes an **instance method** but if you `extend` the module then it becomes a **class method**.

```
module Const
  def format
    puts 'Done!'
  end
end

class Car
  include Const
end

Car.new.format # Done!
Car.format # NoMethodError: undefined method format for Car:Class

class Bus
  extend Const
end

Bus.format # Done!
Bus.new.format # NoMethodError: undefined method format
```

Answer (score 40):

```
module Foo
  def self.hello # This is a class method
    puts "self.hello"
  end

  def hello # When you include this module, it becomes an instance method 
    puts "hello"
  end
end

Foo.hello #=> self.hello

class Bar
  include Foo
end

Bar.new.hello #=> hello
```

Comment: what if you have some other method in Foo and you want to access hello within that method? How would you do it?

Comment: I don't get it. you can just call 'hello' inside that method.

Comment: Simple but complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, with modules, these things should be happening :

- Autoload path in application.rb, add:

  ```
  config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
  ```
- Place module in /lib
- Include module with `include NAMEOFMODULE`

If the module name has an underscore like "game_engine", you need to use `include GameEngine`

Comment: i cannot access the method within the same module:

Comment: something like this module Constants
  # To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.

   def remove_formatting(original)
    converted = original.replace(original.gsub!(/\W+/, ''))
    return converted
   end

  Name = "This is a name"
  
end