# Calling a method within a module

Tags: ruby

I have two files. File `X` is:

```
module A
    module B    
        XYZ = "5"    
        def testx
            puts "Test"
        end
    end
end
```

File `Y` is as follows:

```
require_relative "./B/X"

def test
 puts A::B::XYZ
 puts A::B.testx
end
```

I am trying to call `testx` of file `X` within `Y`, but it is not working. However, the call to constant`XYZ` is successful.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** File `Y` needs a class structure as @AlexN pointed out, and include module `B`, then `testx` can simply be called. File `Y` becomes as follows:

```
require_relative "./B/X"
    module A
       class test
       include B        
       def        
          puts self.method("testx")
       end
    end
end
```

Comment: `XYZ` is called a _constant_, not a variable, fyi.

Comment: @PetrGazarov thanks for the feedback, see the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
module A
    module B    
        XYZ = "5"    
        def self.testx
            puts "Test"
        end
    end
end
```

The method has to be a class method. See this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/5417596/1166593.

Comment: I seem to solve it, I indeed needed to use a class structure in Y, and include model B, then I can just call testx

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a class here. Here is how to do it with just modules:

```
module A
  module B    
    extend self
    XYZ = "5"    
    def testx
        puts "Test"
    end
  end
end
```

Executing `A::B.testx` now outputs *Test*. The problem is not related to the *nesting* of modules. The problem would be the same, if you had defined `testx` directly under `A`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I guess the "extend self" is then required in many classes (I have many classes like X) which makes the class solution less redundant, correct me if I am wrong :)

Comment: The downvote is mine.True, this creates a class method `testx`, but it also creates an unwanted instance method with the same name. It's a bizarre alternative to simply creating a class method directly.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the comment/feedback